# AutoCompleteTextView cannot be found by Id for API level 10 and 12, but works fine with newer versions

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview, findviewbyid

I am trying to have an AutoCompleteTextView which works with Google places api.
It works perfectly fine with Android Api levels 17, 18. 
But the line below returns null for my AutoCompleteView. 
In developers documentation I did not come across anything that suggest low api levels are not supported or something.

The line which returns null for Api 10 and 12:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_barff);
```